# What is causing jQuery UI to slide instead of fade?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, polymer, slide, fade

I'm using jQueryUI and a Polymer popup dialog, and I'm hiding a div and then loading data of a profile photo from ajax and popuplating the div with an image element and having it fade in. As far as I know, it's doing this the same exact way in another section that fades in fine instead of sliding. I removed a lot of code here as I found it has no influence to the problem.

```
function supervisorAccountPopup(e) {

    var button = e.target;

    while (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog') && button !== document.body) {
        button = button.parentElement;
    }


    if (!button.hasAttribute('data-dialog')) {

        return;

    }

    var dialogID = button.getAttribute('data-dialog');
    var dialog   = document.getElementById(dialogID);

    if (dialog) {

    $('#supervisorPopupProfilePic').hide();


        dialog.open();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'getProfileImage.php',
            data:{'userID':<? echo $createdByID; ?>, 
                  'size'  :'big'},
            tryCount:0,
            retryLimit:5,
            cache:false,
            success: function(data) {   

                var profileData = JSON.parse(data);

                if(profileData[0].profilePhotoFullpath != ""){

                    $('#supervisorPopupProfilePic').html("<img class='profileImgPopup' id='supervisorPopupProfilePicIMG' src='uploads/profile/" + profileData[0].profilePhotoFullpath + "?" + new Date().getTime() + "'>");

                    var supervisorPopupProfilePic = document.getElementById('supervisorPopupProfilePicIMG');

                    supervisorPopupProfilePic.onload = function () {
                        $('#supervisorPopupProfilePic').show('fade');       
                    };

                }else{

                    $('#supervisorPopupProfilePic').html("<img id='supervisorPopupProfilePicIMG' class='profileImgPopup' src='uploads/profile/_default/defaultProfileImage_big_noBorder.png'>");

                    var supervisorPopupProfilePic = document.getElementById('supervisorPopupProfilePicIMG');

                    supervisorPopupProfilePic.onload = function () {
                        $('#supervisorPopupProfilePic').show('fade');       
                    };

                }


            },
            error : function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown ) {

                this.tryCount++;

                if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                    //try again
                    $.ajax(this);
                    return;
                }    

                return;

            }
        });

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the fade option here: $('#supervisorPopupProfilePic').show('fade');

To slide the content in and out, you would use slideToggle() or slideDown() if you only need the single action. You wont need show();

```
button.click(function() {
  $('#supervisorPopupProfilePic').slideToggle( "slow", function() {

  });
});
```

or

```
button.click(function() {
  $('#supervisorPopupProfilePic').slideDown( "slow", function() {

  });
});
```

Comment: No, I'm saying it is sliding right now, but I don't want it to. I want it to fade, but for some reason it is sliding.